# recursion through hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion

I'm doing a bit of recursion through hashes to build attr_accessor and class instances.
I get all of the value from a main hash.
I use it to describe an event (dance class and club) and I'd like to be able to store the info like this:

```
data = {:datetime => '2011-11-23', :duration => '90', :lesson => {:price => '£7', :level => 'all'}, :club => {:price => "4"}
```

so that I can easily retrieve `lesson[:price]` and `club[:price]`.

With the recursion that I have in place, I check every item of the main hash to see if the value is a hash. If it is I restart the recursion and populate all of the values.
The problem is that I can't have 2 variables of the same name as `lesson[:price]` collides with `club[:price]`.

This is the recursion:

```
class Event
 #attr_reader :datetime, :duration, :class, :price, :level
   def init(data, recursion)
    data.each do |name, value|
     if value.is_a? Hash
     init(value, recursion+1)
   else
     instance_variable_set("@#{name}", value)
     self.class.send(:attr_accessor, name)
   end
  end
end
```

It skip the lesson and club level and add all of their inner values to the instance list.

Is it possible to actually append the name of skipped level so that I can access it through `my_class.lesson.price`, `myclass.club.price` instead of `myclass.price`

Comment: There is the problem with your hash that it contains 2 identical keys (which is not possible). It is not a problem if different instances of hashes have the same key, however.

Comment: Oops, didn't notice the duplicated club entry. the idea is lesson{price} and club{price}, the nested variable have the same name and i'd like to be able to access them witout having to rename them like classprice and lessonprice.

Comment: There are some solutions that look quite nice towards the end of http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/01/ruby-hashtomod.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to change the API you use currently. Here is the corrected code:

```
class Event
  #attr_reader :datetime, :duration, :class, :price, :level
  def init(data, stack = [])
    data.each do |name, value|
      if value.is_a? Hash
        init(value, stack << name.to_s)
        stack.pop 
      else
        new_name = stack.empty? ? name : stack.join("_") + "_" + name.to_s
        instance_variable_set("@#{new_name}", value)
        self.class.send(:attr_accessor, new_name)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It is the following idea:

- Replace `recursion` it is not used anyway with a stack for the keys used.
- Every time, you go into the recursion, the stack is appended the new key.
- Every time, the recursion is left, the stack is reduced (by using `pop`).

The code for appending the things together is ugly, but it works. The output after using your example data:

```
irb(main):042:0> e.init(data)
=> {:datetime=>"2011-11-23", :duration=>"90", :lesson=>{:price=>"7", :level=>"all"}, :club=>{:price=>"4"}}
irb(main):043:0> e
=> #<Event:0x2628360 @datetime="2011-11-23", @duration="90", @lesson_price="7", @lesson_level="all", @club_price="4">
```

Comment: Well, I'm glad  I joined stackoverflow today, learning a lot :)  Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome! Stackoverflow is the best since sliced bread ;-)